# MySQL Select statement returning no matches on one column

Tags: mysql, select

I have a VERY basic database that i need to return certain results for.

The table i'm searching is called `Judge` and it contains the columns:

```
Judge_id, Name, Suburb
```

In my select statement I need to return the results of everyone who lives in Adelaide and Sydney.

So I use:

```
SELECT *
FROM judge
WHERE Suburb LIKE ('Adelaide' 'Sydney');
```

but this returns no results. Also tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM judge
WHERE Suburb = 'Adelaide' 'Sydney'
```

Still no results.

If I only search for just Adelaide however:

```
SELECT *
FROM judge
WHERE Suburb = 'Adelaide'
```

I get ONE result. However there are multiple matches, and the result that is returned in the last one on the table (if that has anything to do with it).

If I do:

```
SELECT *
FROM judge
WHERE Suburb LIKE '%Adelaide%'
```

I get both matches. But if i leave the % signs out, I only get the one match again.

If i do a search for any of the "Name"s of the people in the table, i can get matches back for any of them fine. So why am i having trouble getting a match for Suburb?
Thanks for any help

EDIT:

Table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE JUDGE (
   Judge_id    INT     NOT NULL,
   Name        VARCHAR(25),
   Address     VARCHAR(25),
   PRIMARY KEY (Judge_id)
);
```

and data:

```
1  Smith      Melbourne
2  Green      Cootamundra
3  Gates      Dunkeld
4  Smith      Sydney
5  Russell    Adlaide
6  Schofield  Adelaide
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Ravi's suggestion - but if you really do want to use "LIKE" then use:

```
SELECT * FROM judge WHERE Suburb LIKE 'Adelade%' or Suburb LIKE 'Sydney%';
```

Only of any use if there are suffixes to that field data though.

Comment: This returns one result for Sydney, but none for Adelaide... Getting very confused

Comment: From reading your edited question you could have some spaces or other information at the start/end of the data you're looking for, so use '%Adelaide%' or suburb like '%Sydney%'

Comment: Ok this seemed to work. Thanks! Not sure whats happening.. i don't seem to have any blank spaces in front or behind the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM judge WHERE Suburb in ('Adelaide' , 'Sydney');
```

You can also mention more suburbs separated by comma.

Comment: That string only retruns one result for Adelaide. There should be 3 matches all up, 2 for Adelaide, and 1 for Sydney.

Comment: Please share your table data.It will help us find out the issue.